# how to override a computed property in swift

Tags: swift, properties, overriding

I just try the swift's new feature, [Overriding Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID196)

```
class B {
    var c:Int = 3 {
        didSet {
           c = 5
        }
    }
}
class C: B {

    override var c:Int = 9 {
        didSet {
            c = 10
        }
    }
}
```

but it will raise complier error:

```
Playground execution failed: super.init called 
multiple times in initializerinteger overflows 
when converted from 'Builtin.Int32' to 'Builtin.Int8'
```

Comment: The specific error you are reporting steam from the overriding of the `init()` 'cause you are giving a different default value to `c`. Try explicitly writing the initialisers. _Anyway_ it appears to me that the `didSet` overloading don't work properly in the playground :-/

Comment: If you delete the `= 9` part, it'll work. The original code doesn't compile because you can't override a inherited property with a stored property. You have to override one with a computed property.